# Are tool identification questions appropriate?

Tags: discussion

Noticing that there are no `tool-identification` or `identification` tags, I found [this meta discussion](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1162/67049) where consensus was that such a tag wasn't needed or appropriate.

However, nothing in that question indicates that tool identification is, or is not, appropriate for this site.  Is it allowed to post such questions, or are they considered off-topic?

As an example, this device found in a toolbox is sufficiently weird that I'd really like to find out what it is:

[image: Strange tool with red/green flag]

Comment: I think a key question is whether the unknown object would be used for home improvement. Without knowing what a given object is in advance, some additional context is probably needed to know whether it's on topic.

Comment: I found it in one of my father's toolboxes; the toolbox in question is decidedly bent towards plumbing tools and equipment.  The other option that it would have been used for is "boat improvement", which is kind of like home improvement but with twin diesels.  Does that help contextualize the question?

Comment: I'm giving more generic advice of how to know if it's very likely off topic, not really focusing on your specific object. Whether identification of home improvement tools is on topic, I'll leave up to the community, but I'm pretty sure they've been asked and answered before.